# using nvarchar on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have to migrate a bunch of SQL queries from Azure to BigQuery. I am currently working on a line that I have a hard time to "convert" to BigQuery:

```
case when [source_system] like '%SAP%' then cast('London' as nvarchar(max))
```

nvarchar is not available on BigQuery, what would be an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STRING`

Variable-length character (Unicode) data.
Input `STRING` values must be UTF-8 encoded and output `STRING` values will be UTF-8 encoded. Alternate encodings like CESU-8 and Modified UTF-8 are not treated as valid UTF-8.

All functions and operators that act on `STRING` values operate on Unicode characters rather than bytes. For example, functions like `SUBSTR` and `LENGTH` applied to STRING input count the number of characters, not bytes.

Each Unicode character has a numeric value called a code point assigned to it. Lower code points are assigned to lower characters. When characters are compared, the code points determine which characters are less than or greater than other characters.

**Parameterized Type**

`STRING(L)`

String with a maximum of `L` Unicode characters allowed in the string, where `L` is a positive `INT64` value. If a string with more than `L` Unicode characters is assigned, throws an `OUT_OF_RANGE` error.